# Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.DocumentQueryException: Expression with NodeType 'Conditional' is not supported

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, odata, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

When using OData filter operator `any` on a nested property it fails returning:
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.DocumentQueryException: Expression with NodeType 'Conditional' is not supported.

The Json structure is as follows:

```
[
{
  "id":1,
  "vessel":{
    "classes":[
      {
        "name":"a"
      },
      {
        "name":"b"
     ]
  }
},
{
  "id":2,
  "vessel":{
    "classes":[
      {
        "name":"c"
      }
     ]
  }
}
]
```

the odata query looks like this:

```
MyData?$filter=vessel/classes/any(x: x/name eq 'a')
```

Im using OData 8 with net6

How can I use the any operator on the nested property? (other operators work)

I tried moving the classes array to the root level, then the query looks like this:

```
MyData?$filter=classes/any(x: x/name eq 'a')
```

and this works

Comment: Please see https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/3542

Comment: https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/738

Answer (score 0):

```
[EnableQuery(HandleNullPropagation = HandleNullPropagationOption.False)]
```

adding this fixed it

Comment: Do you might know the answer to this one as well?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75245865/copybatchrequestproperties-and-deleterequestcontainer-replacement-in-aspnetcore