# CopyBatchRequestProperties and DeleteRequestContainer replacement in AspNetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

I got a code which used the `HttpRequest` from `Microsoft.AspNet.Http` namespace and after updating the code, I am now using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` namespace along with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` v8.0.12.

In the code I had invoked these methods for OData batch operation:

```
changeSetContext.Request.CopyBatchRequestProperties(request);
changeSetContext.Request.DeleteRequestContainer(false);
```

After the namespace change, these methods are no longer defined. Is there a replacement in the AspNetCore namespace version > 8 for what these methods were doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have some bad news. There is no direct equivalent in v8.0.12. So you will need to find an alternate solution or write your own implementation. The following is how you might create your own implementation:

CopyBatchRequestProperites:

```
public static class HttpRequestExtensions
{
    public static void CopyBatchRequestProperties(this HttpRequest targetRequest, HttpRequest sourceRequest)
    {
        foreach (var property in sourceRequest.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(sourceRequest);
            property.SetValue(targetRequest, value);
        }
    }
}
```

using:

```
var sourceRequest = changeSetContext.Request;
var targetRequest = new HttpRequest();
targetRequest.CopyBatchRequestProperties(sourceRequest);
```

for deleting a request container you can try setting its value to null.

DeleteRequestContainer:
You can make the example an extension method of the HttpRequest class:

```
public static class HttpRequestExtensions
{
    public static void DeleteRequestContainer(this HttpRequest request, bool deleteRequest)
    {
        if(deleteRequest)
        {
            var request = changeSetContext.Request;
            request.Headers.Remove("OData-Version");
            request.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
            request.Content = null;
        }
    }
}
```

using

```
var request = changeSetContext.Request;
request.DeleteRequestContainer(false);
```

This might not work for your exact case but should help to give you an idea of what you could probably do. Might even be worth looking at the source code in version 7.5.8 to see if you can figure out how to recreate it for yourself.

Comment: And there weren't any other side effects to invoking the previous method besides the direct copy and delete of properties?

Comment: This isn't invoking the previous methods this is creating your own version, that does the same thing. You can name them whatever you choose and they don't reference the old versions in anyway.

Comment: I didn't say anything about the name. I asked if there any other side effects to the previous methods compared to the ones you showed here

Comment: Sorry for the super late reply @CodeMonkey but no I didn't notice any side effects when I tried this.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the documents:

[CopyBatchRequestProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.batch.batchhttprequestmessageextensions.copybatchrequestproperties?view=aspnet-webapi-5.2) Method in Asp.Net

[CopyBatchRequestProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnet.odata.batch.httprequestextensions.copybatchrequestproperties?view=odata-aspnetcore-7.0) Method in Asp.Net Core

[DeleteRequestContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnet.odata.extensions.httprequestmessageextensions.deleterequestcontainer?view=odata-aspnet-7.0) Method in Asp.Net

[DeleteRequestContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnet.odata.extensions.httprequestextensions.deleterequestcontainer?view=odata-aspnetcore-7.0) Method in Asp.Net Core

The request should be type of  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest` instead of `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage`

Comment: That's relevant for Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData v7.5.8 but I'm using v8.0.12..